# JAXB and interface method parameters

Tags: java, jaxb

I try to handle a Method in my class, which has a Interface as Parameter:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "insertResource")
  public abstract void insertResource(ResourceDto resource)
      throws RemoteException;
```

ResourceDto is just a simple interface:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AnyTypeAdapter.class)
public interface ResourceDto extends Dto, Resource, Serializable
{
}
```

You can see, I tried the AnyTypeAdapter to handle the interface, but it doesn't work.
Can anyone tell me, what I do wrong or how I can handle Interfaces as Parameters (and as return value) in JAXB?

Comment: what does not work? Can you explain the problem?

Comment: So when I try to call the web service with the endpoint, I get a IllegalAnnotationsException - JAXB can't handle interfaces (because of interface ResourceDto)

Endpoint e = Endpoint.create(new MyClass());
e.publish(<url>);